# Sitecore 8.1 - where did Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications go?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We have a Sitecore 7.5 site and we're testing an upgrade to 8.1. Our 7.5 solution utilizes the Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications namespace to prompt the user in Page Editor for certain conditions.

Our project won't build under Sitecore.Kernel 8.1 because that namespace is no longer there. Does anyone know if it was moved or renamed? Or is there a new method to to show user messages in Experience Editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show it as still being there in 8.1 update 1. Its in the Sitecore.ExperienceEditor dll.

See the Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config

```
      <getPageEditorNotifications>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.GetWorkflowNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.NeverPublishNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.FallbackFieldsCountNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.ReadOnlyNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.GetLockingNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.GetWriteAccessDeniedNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
      </getPageEditorNotifications>
```

Comment: So, they moved it from Sitecore.Kernel.dll to Sitecore.ExperienceEditor dll. Thanks.